# What Xubuntu release is OSGeo-Live based on

Tags: osgeo-live

Does anyone know where to find a list of parent Xubuntu releases for each OSGeo-Live version, and where there is a roadmap for future releases? I was able to find this out for OSGeo-Live 7.0 only by running it and querying the release from the command line:

```
user@osgeolive:~ $ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.3 LTS
Release:        12.04
Codename:       precise
```

Since OSGeo-Live 7.0 is less than one year old, I assume that the older version of Xubuntu means that as a rule the project only bases on LTSes. I'm asking because I'm considering when and whether to upgrade, and I wouldn't want to do so until OSGeo-Live is based on Xubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Why would this possibly make a difference? Its a live image, so you can just test each one to see if you like it! From http://courses.neteler.org/476/, 7.9 is based on Xubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. Probably an 8.x number would be associated with the 14.04 builds, but predictions are hard, especially about the future.

Comment: Thanks for the info about 7.9. I'm still interested in knowing about the future release, and presumably this is being planned somewhere. Given the people who frequent this site, I didn't really think this question would be considered a "hard prediction".

Answer (score 2):

Why would this possibly make a difference? Its a live image, so you can just test each one to see if you like it!

However, from courses.neteler.org/476, 7.9 (originally version 48) is based on Xubuntu 12.04.4 LTS. Note that there is a new version (49) of 7.9 for the so-called "Heartbleed" vulnerability.

The next version will almost certainly be 8.0, and is based on 14.04. Current [nightly builds are available](http://aiolos.survey.ntua.gr/gisvm/dev/). There is a release schedule available at https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Al9zh8DjmU_RdE1SYUN3YWJ2N1NpSUczbW9IRWZNclE&hl=en_GB#gid=0 but the tl;dr; version is "FOSS4G Portland"

You can also [build your own live GIS disk](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Live_GIS_Build).

If you have more specific questions, you might like to try the [project specific mailing list or IRC](http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Live_GIS_Disc#Contact_Us).